# What does this css selector do?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I spotted this (to me) curious css style in the default Site.css file of an ASP.NET MVC project:

```
.text-box.multi-line
{
    height: 6.5em;
}
```

Is `.text-box.multi-line` just the name of a class that happens to have a dot in the middle of it, or is this a nesting of two classes? Or is it something else entirely? Can you explain?

And can you provide a usage example?

**Edit**

Thanks for all the answers. This seems to be an omission from the [w3schools css reference page](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_reference.asp).

Comment: Regarding the omission.. it's not surprising, see: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: thank you @thirtydot, wasnt aware there was so much against w3schools, i was personally, but nice to know there are a lot of others

Comment: @thirydot, thanks for that link. Interestingly, HTML Dog (one of the recommended sites) doesn't have what I was looking for either :(

Comment: @DanM: Try SitePoint: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/classselector that page discusses `div.foo.bar`.

Comment: @DanM sitepoint reference does :) @thirtydot great minds think alike.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it matches an item with both classes, ie.

```
<textarea class="text-box multi-line"></textarea>
```

It will not match if the item only has 1 of the classes.
It will match if the item has those two classes plus additional ones.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the element has **both** classes.

It will select an element with the class `text-box` that also has the class `multi-line`

This would be the same:

```
.multi-line.text-box {}
.text-box[class~="multi-line"] {}
```

An example:

```
<p class="multi-line text-box some-other-class"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's selecting an element like this:

```
<* class="text-box multi-line"></*>
```

Any element that has *both* the `text-box` and `multi-line` classes.

Answer (score 2):

It will select this element:

```
<textarea class="text-box multi-line" />
```

Or any element with both the `text-box` and `multi-line` classes for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick little fiddle to show the difference:

http://jsfiddle.net/sGn2v/

basically it'll match an element having BOTH classes!